# Will my ID scan at check-in?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, check-in

I have a flight booking, and below is a section of the airline's reservation data:

`1.SSR DOCS B2 HK1 GVAMSQ0872S26OCT/P/SWE/*****125/SWE/04MAY1995/M/02FEB2023/DEVECSERI/ANDRE`

`2.SSR DOCS B2 HK1 MSQTBS0735S26OCT/P/SWE/*****125/SWE/04MAY1995/M/02FEB2023/DEVECSERI/ANDRE`

However, my ID card's machine-readable code starts with `I<SWE` rather than `P<SWE` (P being used in passports).

Will my ID scan at check-in, or should I ask the airline for a correction (so the handling agent doesn't have to type it in manually)?

Comment: is there a chance you could do it online ?

Comment: @Fattie Nope, it only asks for the document number, not type.

Comment: It can't hurt to ask, can it?  The worst that can happen is that they say "no."

Comment: I'm not sure publishing the full MRZ info is wise... I would probably black out a few things...

Comment: Are you talking about a gate manned by a human or a fully electronic gate? If there's a human nearby you can always ask them to correct it.

Comment: @jcaron That's not my MRZ, but a section of the reservation info. I only wrote the very beginning of my MRZ

Comment: @JonathanReez TAlking about bag drop, since I always check-in online but (except with Ryanair and Wizz) print the boarding pass at bag drop.

Comment: @Coke it may not be your MRZ, but it does (did) contain your ID number, birthdate, and full name.

Comment: But is the bag drop manned or automated? If its manned then it doesn't matter

Comment: @JonathanReez Manned, but both times checking in with AAS at ZRH, they took about 10 minutes to put in the data manually (dunno if it was due to the letter mismatch, a computer issue or just them being noobs, but still). Now I'm checking in with DNATA at GVA (for a Belavia flight), and would mainly like to know if I should either take an earlier train from Zurich to GVA or print the BP from home (which I don't normally do to minimise the waste of A4 paper), unless the letter mismatch is not an issue of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name, and date of birth matches. You should not be worried. It should scan without issues.

In the worst case, the agent will have to change document type manually.

Answer (score 2):

I recently flew Birmingham UK to Amsterdam on KLM.  I tried to use my Irish passport card at the self-service terminal to print my baggage tag.  It told me to insert my passport or ID card though the picture only showed a passport being used.  I tried a very large number of times in various orientations but none worked.  I had to go to a manned desk where my card was happily accepted.  I asked about the self-service terminal and was told that it did not work with cards.

I like the idea of travelling with just my card but this problem and the similar one at automated passport gates is a discouragement.

Comment: I wonder if those automated machines would happily work if you just use a laminated copy of your passports photo page...

Comment: It's likely because the document type code of the passport card is IP, which the kiosk may not be programmed for. My ID (code I) works flawlessly at the KLM kiosk in Birmingham

Comment: @Coke Yes, your question prompted me to look at my documents.  I plan to post a question on the subject.  The MRI of my full size passports start P<GBR and P<IRL but my passport card uses a totally different format: IPIRL and the following data is arranged quite differently.  So, this was my problem rather than that it was a card.  The card scanned immediately without problems at the desk.  If so, it is annoying that Ireland  don't use I<IRL.  I need a third nationality.

Comment: @badjohn The "type" covers two characters, and the "country" space three characters, and different countries' IDs use them differently. For example, in Germany it's IDD<<, in France IDFRA and in Sweden I<SWE. All of these work, I've been told. It's rather the IP designation that's making life difficult for the kiosks, if I had to guess.

Comment: @Coke I added a new question on the format of the MRI.  https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/123445/format-of-mri-on-passports-and-id-cards